# How to remote debug maven build?

Tags: maven, debugging, raspberry-pi, remote-debugging

I'm writing a Scala app intended to work on Raspberry pi. I'm using Pi4J library for GPIO handling, because of that I can't run my code on my development machine.

For this project I'm using Maven and some plugins to help me with deployment (barefacedly stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148025/how-to-deploy-a-jar-onto-raspberry-pi-2-using-maven-plugin)). It orders Maven to connect to my Rpi via ssh, copies the .jar and executes it. Here is the code:

```
    <build>
        <!--This plugin will Transfer the executable JAR file to the Pi and runs it -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <!-- ensure the target directory exists on the Raspberry Pi -->
                            <sshexec host="${pi.host}" port="${pi.port}" username="${pi.user}"
                                password="${pi.password}" trust="true" failonerror="false"
                                verbose="true" command="mkdir --parents ${pi.deployDirectory}" />

                            <!-- copy the JAR file to the Raspberry Pi -->
                            <scp
                                file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"
                                todir="${pi.user}:${pi.password}@${pi.host}:${pi.deployDirectory}"
                                port="${pi.port}" trust="true" verbose="true" failonerror="true">
                            </scp>

                            <!-- run the JAR file on the Raspberry Pi -->
                            <sshexec host="${pi.host}" port="${pi.port}" username="${pi.user}"
                                password="${pi.password}" trust="true" failonerror="false"
                                verbose="true"
                                command="java -jar ${pi.deployDirectory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </build>
```

Thanks to that, when I execute `mvn install` Maven deploys and runs my .jar file on my Rpi. It works fine when it works fine, however when something crashes or doesnt work as expected I cannot debug my app. How can I add debugger to this setup, to allow me using breakpoints?

I tried adding parameters to `java -jar filename`, like `java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y -jar filename`, but when it starts I get the answer `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000`. Exactly the same prints when I run `mvnDebug install`, but then it doesn't even want to compile, it throws me this message straight away.

Comment: If you like to remote debug your app you have to give options to the starting jvm ....Just search for remote debugging JVM ...

Comment: Tred that, I updated my question

Comment: You should of course not try to debug Maven. You should add the parameter to the `java -jar ..` configuration (BTW. I would use exec-maven-plugin instead of ant plugin).. Afterwards Start your IDE and start it...Furthermore what is such as complicated to start the java -jar on Raspberry directly instead via Maven build ?

Comment: I'm using this plugin just because of lazyness. Using that I can deploy and run my app using one command, without the need to login on raspberry using putty and manually running the jar. You say by running it directly from Rpi it will work? If yes, how to connect my IDE (Intellij) to detect that and handle debugging?

Comment: Start the `java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y -jar ..` and afterwards start your IDE with Remote debugging...Either you do it directly on the PI or via Maven build...